# getting method <init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V not found while connecting to ActiveMQ in Linux environment

Tags: java, activemq-classic

i am unable to execute the java code, successfully, which tries to connect to ActiveMQ in cloud(linux environment).

The same code works fine when running from local system(windows environment).

I am able to get consumer count and queue size.

But in cloud environment i am getting below error:

**org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory: method (Ljava/lang/String;)V not found**

Unable to get any clue what this means.

Comment: Where is the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically when you hit a `method ... not found` in Java it means that your application is using a different version of the library at runtime than the version that you compiled against.  You should ensure that the ActiveMQ client libraries in the cloud environment where it doesn't work are the same libraries you're using in the local environment where it does work.

Comment: Thanks Justin Bertram for providing the insight.Just for clarification... this means that, even if a higher or lower version of library is already present in the environment, still i must ensure same library version should and must be present or included in the environment which was being used to build the jar/job.

Comment: You're essentially correct. Simply put, you need to use the same ActiveMQ client version when you compile and when you run your application.

Comment: Thanks a lot again for the clarification.